# Writing script for automatic process

Tags: scripts

My shell is `bash` and I need to write a script that runs a specific software for each input data in the several folders. For example:

```
gd2p.pl -i /home/WORKDIR/folder1/input1.o
```

Let's say that I have 20 folders in WORKDIR and each folder includes input files. How can I write the script which run the above codes for each folder and each input files automatically?

Comment: yes it's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code.

```bsh
for file in */*; do           # Loop trough any file in any folder
    if [ -f "$file" ]; then   # If the current element is a file
        gd2p.pl -i "$file"    # Run the program
    fi                        # End if
done                          # End loop
```

Comment: @muru: Thanks by your edit. I ever forget the quotes.

Answer (score 1):

My solution would be to use find:

```
find /home/WORKDIR/ -name "input*.o" -exec gd2p.pl -i {} \;
```

That gives you (virtually) unlimited depth in sub-folder structure.